# Curl / Guzzle - get header / response code without body

Tags: http, curl, request, guzzle

To get the statuscode of a website with curl you can use the CURLOPT NOBODY.

Example:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$status = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Is the following example with Guzzle as http library the same:

```
    $guzzle = new Client();
    $req = $guzzle->createRequest('GET', 'http://www.example.com');
    $result = $guzzle->send($req);

    $status = $result->getStatusCode();
```

My goal is to perform a curl/guzzle request without getting the body. Will that request with Guzzle only fetch the status code without wasting bandwith on other data?

Answer (score 16):

In order to get status code of the response without downloading the whole content, you should use "head" method:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->head('http://example.com/');
echo $response->getStatusCode();
```